# Could you list all stops & continuants?

Tags: pronunciation

See this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b11ExX2pouQ) at **17:18**, the lady said that:

> - for the stops, we can't prolong the sound
> - for the continuants, we can prolong the sound as long as we still have air in our lungs.

So, my question is that:

**Could you list all stops & continuants?**

Here is what I think:

Stops: /p/, /b/, /t/, /d/, /k/, /g/

Continuants: all fricatives (f, v, θ, ð, s, z, ʃ, ʒ, h); all nasal (m, n, ŋ); all liquids (l, r); all glide (w,j)

So there are 2 lefts, the affricates (tʃ & dʒ): I don't know whether they are Stops or Continuants

**Could you list all stops & continuants?**

Comment: From [Linguistics: An Introduction](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Affricates+are+an+intriguing+case%22) *Affricates are an intriguing case, because in their articulation they start out as plosives and then turn into fricatives. A convenient way of notating this is to use both specifications for [continuant] and to label them **[—/+continuant]***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: to explain the notation, [−/+continuant] means they start out as a stop (so −continuant) and turn into a fricative (so +continuant).

Comment: @Peter: I just watched [Patrick Winston - Learning: Sparse Spaces, Phonology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L73hY1pBcQI&feature=share) a couple of nights ago. Fascinating stuff all round, but what I particularly took heart from was that even *he* had to stop and think several times when deciding whether to tick the *voiced* and *continuant* columns for a couple of phonemes. But until you just pointed it out, I hadn't actually realised that of course **—/+** above represents the true temporal sequence (*minus **then** plus,* as opposed to the standard notation **+/—** = *plus **or** minus*).

Comment: As the IPA shows, the affricates are meldings of a stop and a fricative, so they start as stops, but can be continued.

Answer (score 2):

Nasals are technically stops as the air is prevented from leaving through the oral cavity by a blockage and forced to leave through the nasal cavity instead. The full term for them is *nasal stops*. However, because all English nasals are stops, we usually call them *nasals* for short.

Affricates can be thought of as having both stop and continuant features.

Comment: Yes, and the reason for treating the nasal consonants as stops in phonology is that they act like stops in phonetic processes.  For instance, in many dialects, p/t/k become glottal stop before stops at the same place of articulation, and e.g., p in "pop bottle" or "Lippman" can be replaced by glottal stop.  Using SPE features, the stops are referred to as non-continuants.

Comment: are you sure, here, they say m, n are continuants https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:+continuant

Comment: @Tom Yes, that def is definitely wrong :( See [here, for example](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J6FMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&lpg=PT38&dq=nasal+stops&source=bl&ots=knV8B5PTgR&sig=-icmgBvDnsNsRuVVM_SQhSDD3Ec&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiirfk5arLAhWCNpoKHXa9Dwg4ChDoAQgnMAM#v=onepage&q=nasal%20stops&f=false).

Comment: @Tom Or [here in this famous book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ALJKvQWP8FAC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=giegerich+nasal+stop&source=bl&ots=k51Y_3jR7u&sig=qqO59fXrC6-dim4C-4tI0tgKdpc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia14qa5qrLAhXsJJoKHcMkAX8Q6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=giegerich%20nasal%20stop&f=false)